# Create Object with Unknown Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a class called `Location` and it can either be `Location<IClub>` or `Location<IRestaurant>`.

I get a record from a database and that record then specifies whether this location is a restaurant or a club.

I need to create Location based on a string value within the record.

I have tried doing this;

```
        object topLoc = null ;

        if (record.type == "club")
            topLoc = new Location<IClub>();
```

but I cannot access any of `Location`'s properties.

I also can't create the object in an if statement as when you leave the if the object will be out of scope.

Comment: Do you have a common interface that you can use for both types, something like ILocation instead of object?

Comment: I can do but then how do i add the iClub or IRestaurant interface to the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like generics are not the tool you need. Rather than using generics to annotate the kind of location, consider using an `enum`.

```
public enum LocationKind
{
    Restaurant,
    Club
}

Location location = new Location(LocationKind.Club);
// set up & use location as you see fit; expose the LocationKind through a
// property or something else along those lines
```

Comment: Hmmm, yeah.  As a last resort but that would involve quite a bit of refactoring of "legacy" code.  <shudder>

Comment: @griegs, you can otherwise use the `dynamic` keyword as the type of `topLoc`, but that means byebye static typing for that part of your code. (Also, it requires you to use the .NET Framework 4 or better.)

Comment: @griegs, yet another option is to create a non-generic superclass of `Location` (IIRC you can call it `Location` too) that will have all the fields that don't depend on the generic type; though I would recommend this approach only as a temporary measure because you usually don't want to add meaningless inheritance.

Comment: I know you're right, and I suspect the best avenue is the Enum method but just the thought of all the rework is driving me to the nearest pub